# Python, How to download images from yandex and google

Tags: python, image, search-engine

I found this "https://github.com/hardikvasa/google-images-download" and i'm usually using it with -u url link, but how i can make it download related images in each images result ? Each images in result have 7 related images when you clicked on it and 6 related images on yandex.

i'm looking for a solution to download(or get direct link) all images + related images with provided image search link (google/yandex)

Thank

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you share what you have tried doing so far as a starting point for others to help you out?

Comment: i'm just using Google Images Download, but i heard someone say selenium is best for download images so i found this too : https://github.com/scirag/selenium-image-crawler but it wont work